# Possible to Insert Table Row that doesn't have any columns?

Tags: html

is it possible to insert a table row that doesn't adhere to any columns? This is, say for example a message displayed or an advertisement placed somewhere inside the table.
Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you mean one row with one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll just have to do the following:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">This is a message</td>
</tr>
```

Setting `colspan` to the number of columns your table has will make this row appear to span the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

no you cant do this since it is not valid.

you cant add Tr without TD.

what you can do is insert with 1 td and use colSpan as much as you need.